# Return In JSON Format, PHP

Tags: php, json

In a project, I have to return user_id, user_age from the database and the return format should be like

> - **user object** which contains user_id and user_age
> - average age of users
> - count of users

the return format should be in JSON format.
I have created user array and encoded to **JSON** by using the method

> json_encode(user);

my code is like this :

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $user["id"]                 = $row["id"];
        $user["name"]               = ucfirst($row["user_name"]);
        $user["date"]               = $row["date_of_treatment"];
        $user["age"]                = $row["age_of_user"];

        // push single user into final response array
        array_push($response, $user);

        $count = $count+1;
        $sum_of_age = $sum_of_age+$row["age_of_user"];

    }

echo json_encode($response);
```

I have calculated the average age ($sum_of_age/$count) and count of returned users ($count), but I don't know how to return average age and count of users with the same json response.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code, including the source of your data.  We can't possibly help if we don't know how you are preparing the variable `user` (which, by the way, should be `$user`)

Comment: @SameeraChathuranga code is edited, hope this is ok now

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd: Try this: http://pastie.org/8959015

Comment: don't use `mysql_`. It's deprecated and it doesn't support prepared statements, whose purpose is to avoid SQL injection attacks. Use `mysqli_` or PDO. Speaking of which, show your SQL code ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I will consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$count=0;
$sum_of_age=0;
$response=array();
$response['users']=array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $user["id"]                 = $row["id"];
    $user["name"]               = ucfirst($row["user_name"]);
    $user["date"]               = $row["date_of_treatment"];
    $user["age"]                = $row["age_of_user"];

    // push single user into final response array
    array_push($response['users'], $user);

    $count = $count+1;
    $sum_of_age = $sum_of_age+$row["age_of_user"];

}

$response['count']=$count;
$response['avg']=$sum_of_age/$count;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: how do i get this in jquery, i mean how to extract the average and count in jquery ?

Comment: @Patrik please try to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578968/decode-json-object-in-jqery

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$users = array();
$sum_of_age = 0;
$count = 0;
$users = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $user["id"] = $row["id"];
    $user["name"] = ucfirst($row["user_name"]);
    $user["date"] = $row["date_of_treatment"];
    $user["age"] = $row["age_of_user"];

    // push single user into final response array
    $users[] = $user;

    $count++;
    $sum_of_age += (int) $row["age_of_user"];
}

$response = array(
    'users' => $users,
    'averageAge' => $sum_of_age/$count,
    'count' => $count

);

echo json_encode($response);
```

This should result in the following json response:

```
{
    "users":[
        { "id" : "1", "name" : "John Doe" , "date" : "2014-03-22 15:20" , "age" : 42 },
        {...},
        ...
    ],
    "averageAge": 42,
    "count": 1337
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $user["id"]                 = $row["id"];
        $user["name"]               = ucfirst($row["user_name"]);
        $user["date"]               = $row["date_of_treatment"];
        $user["age"]                = $row["age_of_user"];

        // push single user into final response array
        array_push($response, $user);

        $count = $count+1;
        $sum_of_age = $sum_of_age+$row["age_of_user"];

    }

$response["average_age"]  = $sum_of_age / $count;
$response["count"] = $count;

echo json_encode($response);

}
```

This is the answer, thanks  @Amal Murali (commented a link), the link you have provided is working.. :-)